# Can I send SMS text messages using all the different phone numbers of my US based users?

Tags: twilio

All my users are in the United States. When someone signs up on my website they enter their cell phone number. Can I use the user's own cell phone number to send a SMS text message via twilio?

I was reading the twilio documentation about subaccounts and I couldn't determine if this was possible or not. They make it sound like you can only send texts using a narrow range of phone numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Today, you can only send text messages from phone numbers you've provisioned from Twilio.  We've got a [FAQ article](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-specify-the-phone-number-a-recipient-sees-when-getting-an-sms-from-my-twilio-app) that describes why.

You can make phone calls from either a Twilio provisioned phone number, or a verified phone number.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks. so what work-around is there for the person receiving the text from the "weird" twilio number? for example, they won't be able to send a text back to my user who initiated the text to them because the text didn't come from my user's cell phone number.

Comment: You would need to keep track of the conversation by storing an association between the original senders number and the Twilio number you use to send the message.  That way when the second party replied you know who to forward the message back to.  We've got a bunch of customers doing things similar to this to faciliate anonymous communication between two parties.  Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm. so that's the common usage pattern? use an additional new number for each of my users ... are there any other techniques? we don't want to do anonymous communication. do you see people just putting the real cell phone number in the initial message so that the recipient can then text them back using that number?